# Determine the integers $a$ such that the congruence $x^4 \equiv a \pmod p$ has a solution for $p = 7, 11, 13$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Determine the integers $a$ such that the congruence $x^4 \equiv a \pmod p$ 
has a solution for $p = 7, 11, 13$

---

This looks similar to previous problem but kinda tricky. I'm not sure where to start... appreciate any help thanks!

Comment: Start with $p=7$. Check all possible $x$ values. Maybe note a connection between $x$ and $-x$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My recommendation: in each case, find a generator of the multiplicative group of the field. For instance for $p=7$, you can use $g=3$, and then you get $g^0=1$, $g^1=3$, $g^2=2$, $g^3=6$, $g^4=4$, $g^5=5$, $g^6=1$. With this “logarithm table”, you can answer all possible multiplicative questions of this sort.

Comment: Thank you :) are you refering to discrete logarithm ? xD I found a related property : $x^k\equiv a\pmod p$ has a solution if $a^{(p-1)/d}\equiv 1 \pmod{p}$ where $d = \gcd(k, p-1)$. but not so sure how to use these...

Comment: Yes. This *is* the discrete logarithm for $p=7$, but you can use it without *thinking* of it as logarithms.

Comment: for $p=7$, im getting $a = 1,4,2$ from your logarithm table

Comment: Yes, that’s it!

Answer (score 3):

First $x^4 \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$ if and only if $x \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$.

Next, you can prove that for invertible elements $x^4 \equiv y^4 \pmod{p}$ if and only if $(xy^{-1})^4 \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$.

Using the existence of primitive roots, you can prove that for odd primes the equation
$$z^4 =1 \pmod{p}$$
has 4 solutions when $4| p-1$ and $2$ solutions otherwise.

Therefore 
$$f: U(\mathbb Z/p \mathbb Z) \to U(\mathbb Z/p \mathbb Z) \\
f(x)=x^4$$

takes $\frac{p-1}{4}$ values when $4|p-1$ and $\frac{p-1}{2}$ values when $4 \nmid p-1$.

Adding back $0$ we get that
Therefore 
$$f: \mathbb Z/p \mathbb Z \to\mathbb Z/p \mathbb Z \\
f(x)=x^4$$

takes $\frac{p-1}{4}+1$ values when $4|p-1$ and $\frac{p-1}{2}+1$ values when $4 \nmid p-1$.

Therefore

- for $p=7$ there are thus $4$ values in the range of $f$.
- for $p=11$ there are thus $6$ values in the range of $f$.
- for $p=13$ there are thus $4$ values in the range of $f$.

And for each $p$ it is very easy to find those values. Just plug in numbers in $f$ until you get as many values as the range (and don't forget that 0,1 are in the range so you only need to find 2,4 respectively 2 more values).

The problem is asking you to find all the $a$'s which are in all three ranges, and the Chinese Remainder Theorem tells you how to find all of them. It also tells you that there are $4 \times 6 \times 4$ distinct values $\pmod{7 \cdot 11 \cdot 13}$ (YIKES).

**P.S.** For the solution you can simply ignore the first part, and simply calculate the range of $f(x)=x^4$ for each $p$. The first part of the problem only calculates how many elements are in the range, so it can save some time when you start plugging numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Using @Lubin 's suggestion we find 
\begin{eqnarray}
x^4 \equiv a \ \text{is solvable}& \mod& 7 &\iff\ a\equiv 0, 1, 2, 4 &\mod 7\\
x^4 \equiv a \ \text{is solvable}& \mod& 11 &\iff\ a\equiv 0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 9 &\mod 11\\
x^4 \equiv a \ \text{is solvable}& \mod& 13 &\iff\ a\equiv 0, 1, 3, 9 &\mod 13\\
\end{eqnarray}

We need to find $a$ satisfying the congruences on the RHS. Now the solution of the system
\begin{eqnarray}
a\equiv u &\mod 7\\
a\equiv v &\mod 11\\
a\equiv w &\mod 13\\
\end{eqnarray}
is
$$a \equiv 11\cdot 13\, p \cdot u + 7 \cdot 13\, q\cdot v + 7 \cdot 11\, r\cdot w \mod 7 \cdot 11 \cdot 13$$

where $(p,q,r)$ are a solution of the congruence
$$11\cdot 13\, p  + 7 \cdot 13\, q  + 7 \cdot 11\, r \equiv 1 \mod 7 \cdot 11 \cdot 13$$

In fact we can find integers $p$,$q$,$r$ so that 
$$11\cdot 13\, p  + 7 \cdot 13\, q  + 7 \cdot 11\, r  =1$$
$p = 5,
q=4
r= -14$
since $11 \cdot 13 \cdot 5 + 7 \cdot 13 \cdot 4 + 7 \cdot 11 \cdot (-14) = 1$
Thus the solution to the system is 
$$a \equiv 11 \cdot 13 \cdot 5 u + 7 \cdot 13 \cdot 4  v + 7 \cdot 11 \cdot (-14) w = 715 u + 364 v - 1078 w \!\!\!\mod 1001 $$

Therefore, the congruence $x^4 \equiv a$ is solvable $\mod 7, 11,  13$ if and only if 
$a \equiv 715 u + 364 v - 1078 w \mod 1001$ for some $u \in \{0,1,2,4\}$, $v \in \{0,1,3,4,5,9\}$ and $w \in \{0,1,3,9\}$ ( and in that case the congruence can be solved with the same $x$, ie solvable $\mod 1001$ ). We find $a \!\!\!\mod 1001$ is one of the $96$ numbers 
$$\tiny{0, 1, 9, 14, 16, 22, 42, 53, 78, 81, 91, 92, 100, 113, 126, 130, 133, 
144, 165, 169, 170, 191, 196, 198, 221, 224, 235, 247, 256, 273, 287, 
289, 295, 302, 308, 312, 352, 364, 378, 386, 399, 429, 438, 443, 445, 
455, 456, 471, 477, 484, 520, 529, 533, 555, 562, 575, 581, 588, 599, 
620, 625, 627, 638, 653, 672, 676, 702, 715, 716, 718, 729, 737, 742, 
757, 763, 770, 781, 793, 806, 807, 819, 828, 841, 848, 858, 861, 872, 
884, 900, 911, 924, 939, 949, 984, 988, 991}$$

As an example, let's find the solutions of the congruence
$$x^4 \equiv 911 \mod 1001$$
We have $911 \equiv 1,9,1 \mod 7,11,13$ so we need to solve 
$$x^4 \equiv 1 \mod 7\\
x^4 \equiv 9 \mod 11\\
x^4 \equiv 1 \mod 13$$
with solutions
$$x \equiv \pm 1 \mod 7\\
x \equiv \pm 5 \mod 11\\
x \equiv \pm1,\pm 5 \mod 13$$
and we get 
$$x \equiv  \pm 715   \pm 364\cdot 5  \mp 1078\cdot (\,1\  \text{or} \ 5) \!\!\!\mod 1001$$
that is 
$$x \equiv 27, 83, 148, 181, 281, 391, 456, 489, 512, 545, 610, 720, 820, 853, \
918, \ \text{or} \ 974 \mod 1001$$

$\tiny{ 27^4=531\,441= 530\cdot 1001+ 911}$